# Pass Dynamically Generated List to multiprocess

Tags: python, multiprocess

I am trying to pass a dynamically generated list of date variables into a multi-process pool.

When I ask for specific dates from `data_2_days()` the multi-process works fine, but if I generate the string using `data_start_and_end()` I get:

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

I believe the string returned is enclosed in quotes and this is what is causing the issue.

Whats the best way to generate the list of date variables to pass into the multi-process pool ?

Thanks

```
def data_start_and_end(start_date,end_date):

    start_date = DateTime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = DateTime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

    no_days = (end_date-start_date).days

    date_str = "("
#    date_end_str = 
    x = 0
    while x <= no_days :
        if x ==0:
            date = start_date

        if date.month < 10:
            month_str = "0"+str(date.month)
        else:
            month_str = date.month

        if date.day < 10:
            day_str = "0"+str(date.day)
        else:
            day_str = date.day            

        date_str = date_str + "['"+ str(date.year) + "','" + str(month_str) + "','" + str(day_str) +"'],"


#        print date_str
        date = date + TimeDelta(days=1)
        x=x+1

    date_str = date_str[:-1] + ")"
    print date_str         
#        dates = 
    return(date_str)

def data_2_days():

    data = ( \
['2018','01','01'], \
['2018','01','02'])

    return(data)

def figure_probs_mp(start_date,end_date):

    data = ZZ_MP_data_lists.data_start_and_end(start_date,end_date)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(36)  
    pool.map(figure_probs, data)
    pool.close()
    pool.join() 


figure_probs_mp(start_date,end_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are not generating a list but a string.

In `data_2_days`, you return a list which containts 2 tuples of 3 elements. In `figure_probs`, when you iterate over this list, you get on tuple at each iteration that you can split in 3 elements.

In `data_start_and_end`, you generate a string representing a list of tuples of 3 elements. Then, in `figure_probs`, when you iterate over this string, you get 1 character at each iteration and the python interpreter returns the `ValueError` because you try to split this single character in 3. Change your `data_start_and_end` function to generate a list of tuple and it should work fine.

```
def data_start_and_end(start_date,end_date):

    start_date = DateTime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = DateTime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

    no_days = (end_date-start_date).days

    list_dates = []
    x = 0
    current_date = start_date
    while x <= no_days:

        if date.month < 10:
            month_str = "0"+str(current_date.month)
        else:
            month_str = str(current_date.month)

        if date.day < 10:
            day_str = "0"+str(current_date.day)
        else:
            day_str = str(current_date.day)          

        list_dates.append((str(current_date.year), month_str, day_str))
        current_date = current_date + TimeDelta(days=1)
        x = x + 1

    return list_dates
```

On a side note, `return` is a statement in python and do not need parenthesis. I think you can also get read of the variable `x` and just iterate while `date <= end_date`.

Comment: Thank you ... seems obvious in hindsight ... have fixed up now generating a list rather than a string ... works great thanks.